# How do I wrap large matrix-style output in Stata

Tags: stata

I would like to wrap large matrix-style output, as per the `corr` commands `wrap` option in an ado file. Unfortunately, `corr` is not implemented as an ado-file, and `pwcorr`, which is implemented as an ado-file that I might model my approach on is missing the wrap option.

It would be useful to understand both how do do this for a fixed output width, and also useful to know how to base the definition of width for fixed output to the width of current window settings.

Comment: Does this mean that you know a column width that you want to work to, or that you want output to wrap given e.g. present window settings?

Answer (score 2):

I use [matlist](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?matlist) for displaying most of my matrices, and it will also take care of wrapping.

More complicated output can be handled by being creative when making the matrix. I find the `dotz` option of `matlist` often helpful in that respect. Another trick I use a lot is the fact that a column and name can have two parts: an "equation name" which can be shared with multiple rows or columns and a "row or column name within the equation".

If you need more flexibility you can look at [frmttable](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=sg97_5).

Comment: That works well for a matrix object, but less well for more complicated matrices, such as the output of `pwcorr , sig` or `oneway , bonferroni`.